# Specify .NET Framework version for a stand-alone ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, version

Could the target .NET Framework version be set not in web.config, but directly in a following page?:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
..............

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
.......
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
........
</head>
<body>
.........
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The version is also tied to the Application Pool in IIS, which is set at the ***Application*** level in IIS, not the page level.